# Is there a good way to capture all the ExternalInterface.call in a Scaleform file

Tags: language-agnostic, scaleform

I'm trying to reverse engineer something. I've got the compiled GFX files and I'd like to know what ExternalInterface.call they are executing. Any suggestion on a good way capture the function names?

Answer (score 0):

The GFX files are just SWF files, so any Flash decompiler (like SWIX or the ones from Sothink) will work. However, you do have to change the file slightly for them to be recognised as an SWF file:

- Rename the file to "*something*.swf"
- Open the file in a hex editor, and change the first three bytes as follows:

  - Compressed files start with "CFX" - change this to "CWS"
  - Uncompressed files start with "GFX" - change this to "FWS"